# How to rotate an object so that it is directed exactly to the coordinates of another object?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra

There is an object. At zero coordinates, the object looks forward, you can say a line comes out of its coordinates. This is the direction of the object. You can imagine with a car. In front of the car is where it looks. Its coordinates in x, y, z are known, as well as its slope in x, y, z in radians or degrees.
The coordinates of the second object are known.
How can you find out how many degrees or radians you need to rotate the car on all axes so that it is directed exactly to the coordinate of the second object?
The object can be rotated along all axes as shown in the figure. The values can be in degrees or radians.

[image: picture]

I tried to find a solution, but I found only ready-made functions for this in the Unity, Unreal Engine engines

Comment: for questions about maths / geometry there is https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You don't need three rotations, only two since the spin about the axis connecting the two bodies can be ignored. So then you basically have a cartesian to spherical coordinate system transformation.

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many degrees or radians you need to rotate an object along all axes (pitch, yaw, and roll), you can use a Delta Find function. This function takes two rotations as input: the current rotation of the object and the target rotation. It returns the rotation that will make the object face the target rotation.

```
// Assume that Object1 has a known starting rotation and you want to rotate it to a specific target rotation
FRotator StartingRotation = Object1->GetActorRotation();
FRotator TargetRotation = ...; // Set the target rotation to the desired value

// Calculate the rotation needed to make Object1 face the target rotation
FRotator DeltaRotation = FindDeltaRotation(StartingRotation, TargetRotation);

// Add the calculated delta rotation to the starting rotation to get the final rotation
FRotator FinalRotation = StartingRotation + DeltaRotation;

// Set the rotation of Object1 to the final rotation
Object1->SetActorRotation(FinalRotation);
```

This will rotate Object1 so that it is facing the target rotation. Note that the Find Delta Rotation function will rotate the object around all axes (pitch, yaw, and roll) as needed to achieve the desired orientation.

All FindDeltaRotation is:

```
FRotator FindDeltaRotation(const FRotator& A, const FRotator& B)
{
    return B - A;
}
```